# How to print random different symbols from this ASCII range?

Tags: c++, random, ascii

Help to make a program displaying on screen for about 10 times random symbols from this range.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char k;
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    k=(rand() % 33) + 15;
    printf("%c",k); }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @nightcracker For some reasons I'm not getting needed symbols.

Comment: For a start: `printf(%c", k);`, not `&k`.

Comment: `k=(rand() % 33) + 15;` generates numbers between 15 and 15+33. You want the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    char chMin = '!';
    char chMax = '~';
    char chRange = chMax - chMin + 1;
    int nCount = 10;
    ::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(::time(nullptr)));
    for(int i=0; i<nCount; ++i) 
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(::rand() % chRange + chMin);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```